# Pointers not giving correct value

Tags: c, pointers

I am doing a project for school and am trying to learn how to use pointers. I am trying to get them to relay the value of X, Y, and Z. However, I keep getting the wrong value. X is supposed to equal 1. Y is supposed to equal 2. Z is supposed to equal 3.

```
{
// Add the C statement(s) necessary to accomplish the task identified in the comments below


double A[3] = {2.718, 3.14, 2.718}; // declare an array A of 3 doubles

A[1] = 3.14;    // put the value 3.14 in the middle location of A

A[0] = 2.718;
A[2] = 2.718;   // put the value 2.718 in the first and last locations of A


printf("The first value of A is %f\n",A[0]);    // print the first value in A


printf("The last value of A is %f\n",A[2]); // print the last value in A


A[2] = A[0] + A[1]; // change the last value in A so that it is the sum of the first two and then print it


printf("The last value of A is %f\n", A[2]);
int B[4] = {10, 25, 50, 100};   // declare an array B of 4 integers with initial values 10, 25, 50, 100


int sum = B[0] + B[1] + B[2] + B[3];
printf("The sum of all four elements in B is %d\n",sum); // print the sum of all four elements in B


printf("Four elements in B in reverse order %d %d %d %d\n",B[3], B[2], B[1], B[0]); // print the four elements in B in reverse order (100, 50, 25, 10)


int X = 1;
int Y = 2;
int Z = 3;
printf("%d, %d, %d\n,",X,Y,Z);  // declare three integers, X Y and Z, assign them the values 1, 2 and 3 and print them


int *P1;    // declare three pointers to integers, P1, P2 and P3


int *P2;
int *P3;
P1 = &X;
P2 = &Y;    
P3 = &Z;    // point P1 to X, P2 to Y, and P3 to Z.


printf("%d, %d, %d\n",P1,P2,P3);    // print the values at X and Y and Z using the pointers P1 to P3
*P1 = 10;
printf("%d", P1);   // using P1 and not X, change the variable X's value from 1 to 10, then print it


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%d, %d, %d\n",P1,P2,P3);` --> `printf("%d, %d, %d\n",*P1,*P2,*P3); `

Comment: You should definitely read a little about pointers. Thats a very basic mistake..

Comment: Yes - pointers do not magically dereference themseves, (unless they are C++ references:).  If they did, you would be unable to tell which vars are accessed via pointers and which are not...

Answer (score 1):

`&X` set the Address of `X` to `P1`.
but,if you want to access the value stored at that address then you should you `*P1`.

What does `*P1` means? It means value stored at this address.

```
P1=&X; //P1 takes address value of X;
```

and if you want to print value at that address then

```
printf("Value of X %d\n",*P1);
```

Answer (score 0):

To access values pointed to by the pointers write

```
printf("%d, %d, %d\n",*P1,*P2,*P3);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
printf("%d", *P1);  
             ^^^^^
```

the same way as you already wrote

```
*P1 = 10;
^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

A pointer is a variable that holds the address of another variable.
A pointer to int `int *p` will hold the address of a variable of type int.
The operator `&` get the address of a variable and the operator `*` gets the value stored at an address.
So:

```
int x = 1;    //An integer i=1
int *p = &x;  // a pointer to int p to which we assign the address of x
//Now suppose x memory address is 100
printf("int=%d, pointer=%d\n", *p, p);  //Will print int=1, pointer=100
```

The value stored at address pointed by `p` is retrieved using the operator `*` and shows its value `1`, but if you put the contents of pointer variable `p` you get `100`.
**But you can't use `%d` to print a pointer, you must use `%p`.**
I used it in `printf` only to demonstrate the problem.